# How to fetch the changed data in a database?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I need to fetch the local names from table A, which have been changed in the past 30 days using SQL.
Do I need to create a backup of a table or is there any other method?
And If creating backup is the only method how do we compare and find out the locally overridden names?

**Table Details:**

```
TREE_ID          (NUMBER)
TREE_NM          (VARCHAR2)
TREE_LEVEL       (VARCHAR2)
UPLEVEL_ID       (NUMBER)
HRCHY_TYPE       (VARCHAR2)
CATG_ID          (NUMBER)
SUBCATG_ID       (NUMBER)
STATUS           (VARCHAR2)
USER_ID          (NUMBER)
CREATE_DATE      (DATE)
EFFCT_START_DATE (DATE)
EFFCT_END_DATE   (DATE)
UPDATED_DATE     (DATE)
TOP_LEVEL_ID     (NUMBER)
```

I need to generate a feed at the end of every month to fetch the changed `TREE_NM`.

Comment: give us a table description please, what version of Oracle?

Comment: you need to be more specific

Comment: Is the server sql or oracle?

Comment: Flagged to move to [dba](http://dba.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @Marshal It is Oracle.

Answer (score 2):

I think there is no default operation in Oracle to do that. A possible workaround could be to include a new column to your table A where you store the `modificationDate`. Then defining a `Before Insert OR Update Trigger` which simply writes the new value (current date) to all rows that have been inserted or updated.

Hope this helps.

Comment: My vote got your reputation into triple digits.  You owe me a beer.

Comment: Ohk thanks.
But I am not supposed to make any changes in the present tables.
Is there any other method that you can suggest?

Comment: Oh ok, that's bad. Unfortunately this is my only idea at the moment, but I'll let you know if another idea comes to my mind. And @DanBracuk Thanks a bunch :)

Comment: You'd be better off updating the stored procedures (or whatever is updating that table) to include the new column, than using a trigger.

Answer (score 2):

If you can't modify the table, this can't be done unless you can modify the apps that modify the table.  If you can do the latter, make a second table with:

```
TreeID NUMBER (foreign key)
LastModifiedDate datetime
```

And write to this table every time the first table is modified.  Then, you can join the two tables together on

```
TableA.TreeID = Table2.TreeID
WHERE Table2.LastModifiedDate >= DATEADD(d, -30, getdate())
```

And that will return all records that were modified in last 30 days.

If you can't modify the database OR the apps, then this is impossible with your current structure, so hopefully you have the ability to make some changes.

**EDIT:**

If historical changes are something that you will need to track for other purposes in the future, you should look into implementing a data warehouse (specifically, look into slowly changing dimensions).

**Second Edit:**

I would seriously question why you're not allowed to add a field to this table.  In SQL Server, you can add fields to tables without impacting the data or applications that access it.  If I were you, I would push pretty hard to add the field to the table instead of creating a more complex and obfuscated database/application structure for no apparent reason.

Comment: Ohk thanks. That'll work.:)

Comment: @Aishwarya You're welcome.  Please upvote any answers that helped you and remember to accept the answer that helps you the most.  Welcome to the forum and good luck!